# will_paginate with jquery: respond_to not responding to js request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, will-paginate

I am using jquery to paginate my application in the same way facebook and twitter do so. The following will load "next" results but it loads the whole html page. It seems it is not responding to the format.js. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Home Controller

def index
  @products = Product.paginate(:per_page => 2, :page => params[:page])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.js { render :template => '/products_home.html.erb' } # Prodcuts home partial
  end
end

Jquery Javascript to execute AJAX
$(function() {
  $(".pagination a").live("click", function() {
 var pagination = $(this).parent();
    $(".pagination").html("Page is loading...");
 $.get(this.href, function(data) {
   $('#show').append(data);
   alert('Load was performed.');
   pagination.hide();
 });
    return false
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

You need to add dataType of "json" to your $.get call.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up using a template instead.